# Updating video title with YouTube Data API v3 gives 'message': 'Parse Error'

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer, youtube-api

I am trying to change the video title using YouTube API V3 with python.
I am using `requests` module to send out a put request. Here is my code:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&key=[KEY] HTTP/1.1"

headers= {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer [ACCESS_KEY]',
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = {
          'id': 'azTrAGHcPX4',
          'snippet': {
            'title': 'This video has views',
            'categoryId': '22',
          }
        }


json = requests.put(url,headers=headers,data=data)
```

On `print(json)` , I get the following error:

```
{'error': {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'parseError', 'message': 'Parse Error'}], 'code': 400, 'message': 'Parse Error'}}
```

Any leads on this error?

Comment: Your URL is incorrect: it should not contain " HTTP/1.1" at its end.

Comment: I get the same error even after removing the " HTTP/1.1"